# Adding gomock tests to project gives "build constraints exclude all Go files" when running test

Tags: go, gomock

I add a test file for a package using gomock to an existing Go project, and now I am getting

> ...imports github.com/golang/mock: build constraints exclude all Go files in /home/bserdar/go/pkg/mod/github.com/golang/mock@v1.4.3

when I run `go test` from one of the packages using gomock. There are no build constraints in my project. Any idea what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not saying any files in your project are excluded, it specifically says all files in github.com/golang/mock are excluded, which is accurate; that's not an importable package, [it doesn't contain anything](https://github.com/golang/mock). You should be importing the subpackages you need - or rather, [per the documentation](https://github.com/golang/mock/blob/master/README.md), you should be generating mocks using the tool, and the generated files should be importing valid packages.

Comment: Thank you for this. I made this mistake before, solved it, and cannot remember how I did this time around.